# Apply variable binning based on another variable's factor breaks

Tags: r

I have two variables with similar distribution, but not the same.

```
var1 <- 1:20
var2 <- 5:25
```

I then bin `var1` and create a new variable:

`bin.var1 <- cut(var1,2)`

Now I want to bin `var2` using the same breaks used for `var1`. Is there a way to do this that isn't manual?

Comment: Have you studied the last example in `?cut`?

Comment: Thanks @Henrik. That extracts the breaks. That is a good start. I still need to figure out a way to apply the same breaks to var2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract the relevant parts from the `cut.default` source code:

```
var1 <- 1:20
var2 <- 5:25

breaks <- 2
nb <- breaks + 1
rx <- range(var1)
dx <- diff(rx)
breaks <- seq.int(rx[1L], rx[2L], length.out = nb)
breaks[c(1L, nb)] <- c(rx[1L] - dx/1000, rx[2L] + dx/1000)

breaks
# [1]  0.981 10.500 20.019

cut(var1, 2)
# [1] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5]
# [7] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5] (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]   
# [13] (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]   
# [19] (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]   
# Levels: (0.981,10.5] (10.5,20]

identical(cut(var1, 2), cut(var1, breaks))
# [1] TRUE


cut(var2, breaks)
# [1] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5]
# [7] (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]   
# [13] (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    <NA>         <NA>        
#   [19] <NA>         <NA>         <NA>        
#   Levels: (0.981,10.5] (10.5,20]
```

Or like @Henrik mentioned, in the last example under `?cut`, you can use the labels

```
## one way to extract the breakpoints
labs <- levels(cut(var1, 2))
(br <- cbind(lower = as.numeric( sub("\\((.+),.*", "\\1", labs) ),
            upper = as.numeric( sub("[^,]*,([^]]*)\\]", "\\1", labs) )))

#       lower upper
# [1,]  0.981  10.5
# [2,] 10.500  20.0

cut(var2, unique(c(br)))

# [1] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5] (0.981,10.5]
# [7] (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]   
# [13] (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    (10.5,20]    <NA>         <NA>        
#   [19] <NA>         <NA>         <NA>        
#   Levels: (0.981,10.5] (10.5,20]
```